# Any way to track rollbacks?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have noticed a strange trend over the past number of weeks: my rep is declining in an untraceable way (i.e. not due to downvotes or old questions that I have answered being deleted).

My rep is hovering at around 2000 these days. Unfortunately, my work (and life) are such that I don't have a great deal of time available for answering questions on sp.se. However, I have some time available for the review queues most days and that is how I choose to contribute on here lately.

Sitting near 2000 rep makes me an easy target for those who are more competitive on the review queues. That is, if my rep dips below 2K, I can't review low quality (LQ) posts and suggested edits. Lately, I have been closer to the lead position on the LQ queue and perhaps others feel threatened by this? Seems weird to even say, but I can't explain my rep decreases.

My guess is that somebody is rolling back my old edits in bulk. Every week, my rep goes down by about 18+ all at once (i.e. overnight -- usually Friday or Saturday night). Is this a system clean-up thing or the result of a member's actions?

I'm wondering:

- Is there a way to track rollbacks?
- Is there a way to find out whether my old edits are being rolled back,  decreasing my rep?

Note: I'm not obsessed with "winning". I just don't think anyone should be a target. My hope is that I am just being paranoid and that nobody on here is malicious. : )

Comment: Looks like the actual post you have edited has been removed by "Community" bot, so no rollbacks on the edits but removal of the whole questions

Comment: The note is "RemoveAbandonedQuestions", read more about the logic behind it here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242544/community-bot-raking-up-abandoned-questions

Comment: Ps, You can see your rep changes in the Activity section of your profile

Comment: I've lost 200+ rep in the past couple of months and none of it is tracked in my profile activity: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/15117/phil-greer?tab=reputation

Comment: Thanks for the link to RemoveAbandonedQuestions, Robert. Glad it's just a bot.

Comment: Oh ok, I can see the changes in your profile (might be moderator powers)